# What are the valid characters for a JavaFX fxml "fx:id" attribute?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

Is this documented somewhere? Is it standard XML guidelines?

I was able to assign fx:id="table$abc" in SceneBuilder, but "table>abc" gave an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In FXMLLoader's source code there is a method `processAttribute(...)` to *"uumh"* process attributes like `fx:id`, `fx:controller` etc. The code to validate the fx:id is:

```
if ( localName.equals( FX_ID_ATTRIBUTE ) )
{
    // Verify that ID is a valid identifier
    if ( value.equals( NULL_KEYWORD ) )
    {
        throw constructLoadException( "Invalid identifier." );
    }

    for ( int i = 0, n = value.length(); i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( !Character.isJavaIdentifierPart( value.charAt( i ) ) )
        {
            throw constructLoadException( "Invalid identifier." );
        }
    }

    fx_id = value;
}
```

so every character in `fx:id` is checked with `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart()`. The

```
Character.isJavaIdentifierPart('$');  // returns true
Character.isJavaIdentifierPart('>');  // returns false
```

Hence using `>` character will throw a `LoadException`, while `$` will not.

There may not exist documentation for valid fx:id names, but at least reading the javadoc of [`Character.isJavaIdentifierPart()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart-char-)  will give you some insights.

Comment: And since it has to be mapped to a Java field using the @FXML annotation, this makes sense, if you think about it.